# disable auto retract option in visual studio 2010 by default

Tags: visual-studio

Everytime I create a new sharepoint project, I forget to uncheck the auto retract option on the project properties. I would like to turn the auto retract option off by default, but I can't find a setting to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per msdn:

This property is exposed as the Auto-retract after debugging option in the SharePoint tab of the SharePoint project property page.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sharepoint.isharepointproject.autoretract.aspx)

I have checked and it is in fact there :)

Comment: I know that I can put this off per project. But I'm searching for a sort of default setting. I always forget to turn the auto-retract option off.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it is possible to set this at a global 'Visual Studio' level. This is specific to SharePoint type projects, so it makes sense that the setting is on that level.

Comment: I already thought so :( , I just wanted to know for sure.